# Moving and cut folders INSIDE watched folder C#

Tags: c#, windows

I am using a FileSystemWatcher and i got 2 cases that don't raise events.
lets say i watch on C:/temp,
In case i have already 2 folders with files inside the watched directory, if i cut-paste or move them inside the watched dir to another folder i dont get any event.
Some one know a way i can get events on this files that moved?

Watched directory:

```
c:/temp
|--test1
|     |--test1.txt
|
|--test2
|     |--test2.txt
```

if i move or cut-paste test2 folder into test1 i don't get event on test2.txt.
EDIT: I'm using the code from FileSystemWatcher docs which can find here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0
hope you can help me, thanks :)

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @YogeshNaik I'm running the code that can found in the docs.link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0

Comment: Have you enabled   watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true; ? I have used the same code. But it was tracking all the changes

Comment: Yes i enabled it, my problem is when im moving folder inside the watched directory. If i move folder  lets say from c:/data into c:/temp i get all the wanted events.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a folder or a file doesn't change it. If you want to track moves, make sure to watch for the `Renamed` event and set the filters appropriately.

As per the documentation:

COPYING AND MOVING FOLDERS

| Event Handler | Events Handled | Performs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OnChanged | Changed, Created, Deleted | Report changes in file attributes, created files, and deleted files |
| OnRenamed | Renamed | List the old and new paths of renamed files and folders, expanding recursively if needed. |

Note that strictly speaking, the file system watcher doesn't watch for changes in *content* - only the filesystem entries. It's possible to change file contents without changing the filesystem entries, so make sure that it's good enough for your use.

Comment: If i move or cut-paste folder from outside into the watched dir i can see the events.  but when i move folders inside the watched dir i cant see any event. i watch the renamed event but i think i still missing something.

Comment: @OrianHindi It's tricky trying to help when you don't provide any source code :) Are you using `NotifyFilters.DirectoryName`?

Comment: Edited the question, I'm using the code in the filesyswatcher docs, the link can be found in the question. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @OrianHindi I suspect the problem might be the `*.txt` filter. The only thing that is renamed is the folder, not the files within - you'd get an event for that, but it gets filtered out because that's what you asked for.

Comment: you were right! now i get event on the folder, is there a way to catch events for the txt files init? or i need to crawl on the folder that changed and look for txt files?

Comment: @OrianHindi You'll need to do the crawling yourself; FileSystemWatcher is just a relatively low level wrapper around filesystem hooks, so if the filesystem doesn't change, it cannot know. And even if it could, it'd be really tricky, since it can't know what kind of things your application wants to do with that information - e.g. if you rename a folder inside the watched folder, should you also reprocess all the files inside? All of those challenges are really about your application logic, not how the filesystem works.